# When this function gets this parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm checking a piece of code which purpose is to print a movie list:

#### HTML CODE

```
<h1>My new Website</h1>
    <form action="formHandler.php" method="GET" id="movieSearchForm">
        <input name="query" type="search" id="search" placeholder="Find a Movie">
        <button>
            Search
        </button>
    </form>
<div id="resultList"></div>
<div id="movieList"></div>
```

#### EVENT HANDLER

```
$('#movieSearchForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var movieTitle = $('#movieSearchForm input').val();

    requestApi(movieTitle, myApp);
});
```

#### API VAR

```
var apiUrl = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=j23zuzdpapq9ny3watvc9kja';¬
```

#### REQUEST API

```
var requestApi = function (query, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: apiUrl,
      data: {
        q: query
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp'
   }).success(callback);
}
```

#### MY APP FUNCTION

```
var myApp = function (response) {
    var movieListData = response.movies;

    var movieList = movieListData.map(function (movieItem) {
        return itemHtml(movieItem.posters.thumbnail, movieItem.title);
    });     

    $('#movieList').get(0).innerHTML = [
      '<ul>',
          movieList.join(''),
       '</ul>'
    ].join('');
};
```

So, `requestApi` gets the movie list needed and `myApp` formats it and inserts it in the web. What I don't understand is how `myApp` gets `response` parameter. Any idea? And one question more, if I want that myApp gets two parameters, what should I change?:

Comment: instead of `success(callback)` write `success(function(response){ callback(response); })`

Comment: `response` is provided by jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - scroll down to "success" and it says that you get `Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )` - this is a function which gets an object as its first param, a string as the second and the `xhr` object as the third

Comment: @Alex: That's not necessary.

Comment: @Joe: Make that an answer.

Comment: @slebetman I was trying to be lazy and not bother answering the other half of the question :P There's a complete answer now heh

Comment: So, if I want to give to the callback function one more parameter, what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response` is provided by jQuery: api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax - scroll down to "success" and it says that you get `Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )` - this is a function which gets an object as its first param, a string as the second and the `xhr` object as the third.

To make your callback take 2 parameters, you can do this:

```
$('#movieSearchForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var movieTitle = $('#movieSearchForm input').val();

    requestApi(movieTitle, function(response) { myApp(response, anotherParam, yetAnotherParam); });
});
```

then just update `myApp` to expect them:

```
function myApp(response, aParam, bParam) {
```

Comment: @Cremix_hellven I assume this answers your "If I want to give it one more parameter, how?" question as well?

Comment: Okie doke, good stuff :) Just making sure everything was answered :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm assuming that `requestApi` accepts two parameters: movie title (a string) and callback (a callback function). Once `requestApi` returns with some data, it will call the callback function similar to doing something like:

```
callbackFunction({title:"stuff", length:"1:09:30"});
```

Where `callbackFunction` is your `myApp` function and your `response` parameter will get all of that nice JSON that was passed from callbackFunction.

Welcome to Async Javascript!